# PHP passing date to SQLServer

Tags: php, sql

I have the following SQL procedure which works on SQL Server Management studio when I execute it

```
 USE [DatabaseName]
 GO

 DECLARE    @return_value int

 EXEC   @return_value = [dbo].[getRegisterSummaryReport]
        @registerID = -1,
        @StartBusinessDate = '1900-01-01 00:00:00',
        @EndBusinessDate = '3000-01-01 00:00:00'

  SELECT    'Return Value' = @return_value

  GO
```

what I want now is to pass the StartBusinessDate and the EndBusinessDate from a PHP function ( sorry I'm very new to PHP) .

here's what I had but for some reason I get false as a respond ( I think I'm not using the proper way to pass the date to my SQL Server).

```
public static function getRegisterSummary($registerId, $startBusinessDate, $endBusinessDate, $dbConnection){
    $date_start = '1900-01-01 00:00:00';
    $date_end = '3000-01-01 00:00:00';
    if($startBusinessDate == "") $startBusinessDate =  date('Y-m-d G:i:s', $date_start); // if startBusinessDate is "" I want the replace it with date_start

    if($endBusinessDate == "") $endtBusinessDate = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', $date_end); 
    $sql = "exec [database1].[dbo].[getRegisterSummaryReport] @registerId = {$registerId}, @startBusinessDate = '{$startBusinessDate}', @endBusinessDate = '{$endBusinessDate}'";
    $results = $dbConnection->query($sql);
    if($results){
        return $results;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: have you checked your sql connection string, is this ok?

Comment: I'm connected to my database I can insert login and do every other procedure but this one.

Comment: there must be an error message with it. what's the error?

Comment: Hi , I'm sorry I'm not that good with PHP so I tried to debug and what I found is the dates are not converted as I want.For example in my code  1900-01-01 00:00:00 will be converted into 1969-12-31 16:31:40. I'm not sure why!

Comment: please read php date() function very carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok This is embarrassing!!

first of all I changed the syntax to this

```
if($startBusinessDate == "") $startBusinessDate = date('1900-01-01');
    if($endBusinessDate == "")   $endBusinessDate =  date('3000-01-01');
```

for some reason this worked with me and passed the correct value unlike when I added

> date('Y-m-d G:i:s', $date_start);

Also I made a mistake in

> if($endBusinessDate == "") $endtBusinessDate = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', $date_end);

I added t after $endtBusinessDate :(